# T-SQL check if event has occurred continuously for 4 hours or more within 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (`event_tbl`) of events that occurred. I need to find out for example if any of the events (`Sales`, `Regcustomer` and `Transfer`) happen continuously for 4 hours with 24 hours.

**event_tbl**:

| empID | staffID | chartTime | Sales | RegCustomer | Transfer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 13:20:00.000 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 14:00:00.000 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 15:00:00.000 | Yes | Yes | No |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 16:00:00.000 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 17:00:00.000 | Yes | No | Yes |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 18:00:00.000 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 19:00:00.000 | Yes | Yes | Yes |

This is my desired result:

| empID | staffID | chartTime | Sales | RegCustomer | Transfer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T7458529 | 31509 | 2022-04-07 | Yes | Yes | No |

So in this example, events `Sales` and `RegCustomer` got flagged as yes because they occurred 4 consecutive times within 24 hours. The `Transfer` event did not.

Don't even know where to begin as it seems to be complex due to how the events are being logged. Grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: *"Continuously for four hours with 24 hours"* what does that mean exactly? In any block of 24 hours there has never been more than 4 hours between? Or it happens every `00` of the hour?

Answer (score 0):

Had to make a few assumptions, but I think this should get you close. Also not sure your expected results are correct. The Transfer event occurs 4 consecutive hours at hours 16-19

### Track if Event Occurred 4 Consecutive Hours in a Single Day

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Event 
DROP Table IF EXISTS #RollingWindowCheck

CREATE TABLE #Event (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),empID CHAR(8),staffID INT,chartTime DATETIME,Sales CHAR(3),RegCustomer CHAR(3),[Transfer] CHAR(3))

INSERT INTO #Event VALUES
('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 13:20:00.000','Yes','Yes','Yes')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 14:00:00.000','Yes','Yes','Yes')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 15:00:00.000','Yes','Yes','No')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 16:00:00.000','Yes','Yes','Yes')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 17:00:00.000','Yes','No' ,'Yes')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 18:00:00.000','Yes','Yes','Yes')
,('T7458529',31509,'2022-04-07 19:00:00.000','Yes','Yes','Yes');

WITH cte_EventDate AS ( 
    SELECT *,ChartDay = CAST(ChartTime AS DATE)
    FROM #Event
)

SELECT *
INTO #RollingWindowCheck
FROM cte_EventDate AS A
OUTER APPLY (
    /*Count distinct hours, since where clause limits it to 4 hours, if 4 distinct hours, then you know they are consecutive.
    Each column only counts that hour though if the Event = 'Yes'*/
    SELECT SalesDistinctHrCnt       = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Sales        = 'Yes' THEN DATEPART(HOUR,DTA.ChartTime) END)
        ,RegCustomerDistinctHrCnt   = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RegCustomer  = 'Yes' THEN DATEPART(HOUR,DTA.ChartTime) END)
        ,TransferDistinctHrCnt      = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Transfer]   = 'Yes' THEN DATEPART(HOUR,DTA.ChartTime) END)
    FROM cte_EventDate AS DTA
    WHERE A.empID = DTA.empID
    AND A.ChartDay = DTA.ChartDay /*Only match to same day*/
    AND A.ChartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DTA.ChartTime) AND DTA.ChartTime /*Match to any times within 4 hours*/
    AND A.ID <> DTA.ID /*Don't match record to itself. Assuming you have a primary key like ID. Alternatively could use A.ChartTime <> DTA.ChartTime but not ideal*/
) AS B

SELECT 
    empID
    ,staffID
    ,ChartDay
    /*Basically if there is a group of 4, you know there were 4 consecutive hours where that event occurred. 
    If not, will be NULL so use ISNULL to return 'No'*/
    ,Sales          = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN SalesDistinctHrCnt = 4 THEN 'Yes' END),'No')
    ,RegCustomer    = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN RegCustomerDistinctHrCnt = 4 THEN 'Yes' END),'No')
    ,[Transfer]     = ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN TransferDistinctHrCnt = 4 THEN 'Yes' END),'No')
FROM #RollingWindowCheck
GROUP BY empID,staffID,ChartDay
```